# Bug in Moderator Election web page while accidental voting same candidate twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

I accidentally(*page loading fiasco*) happened to vote twice for the same candidate as my second preference. As soon as I did that the same candidates name appeared as my Second and Third choice of candidates on the right hand corner of the webpage. Thinking it is some kind of a weird error which might vanish once I refresh the page, I did so but then it showed me an error:

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/election

Now, every-time I click on the [elections link](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) through SO main it redirects me to that error web page. Something seems to be seriously broken here and needs a fixing.

Comment: should work again now

Comment: @balpha: Works.Thanks.